# unrar with long file path

Tags: file, path, long-integer, unrar

I have an .rar achive, when I use right click on file explorer, and use the menu "extract here", I can extract the files sucessfully. but when I use unrar.exe to extract the same achive, I got errors like can not find the specified path.
the path in problem is longger than 260 char.

my question is: how can I unrar a achive  under bat file with long file path?

Comment: Try starting with the archive at `C:\ ` to keep the total path short?

Comment: this can help. but can not solve the problem. because my bat file need deal with many different rar archive, the file path length is uncertain